# NestJS ConfigModule not loading the correct .env file

Tags: nestjs

I have 2 different file with environment variables: `.env.development` and `.env.production`.

I am trying to load the correct file through the ConfigModule like so:

**app.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
      isGlobal: true,
    })
  ],
})
```

In `package.json` I specify the right NODE_ENV per startup script:

```
"start:dev": "NODE_ENV=development nest start --watch",
"start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production node dist/main",
```

My development file contains `PORT=2994` and production contains `PORT=2997`.

In my `main.ts` file I am logging both the PORT and the .env. file path + NODE_ENV of the ConfigService, like so:

```
const port = configService.get<number>('PORT');
console.log('Running on port: ', port);
console.log(`.env.${configService.get('NODE_ENV')}`);
```

The NODE_ENV file path log is always correct (.env.development for development and .env.production for production). The port however, which is supposed to be retrieved from the correct file is logged 2994 on both development and production.

Only when I remove or empty the .env.development file, the production values are used. It seems as if the .env.development will always take precedence over the .env.production file.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I tried your code. The PORT is correct.

Comment: When you run `npm run start:prod`, is the PORT 2997?

Comment: Yes! The PORT is 2997 when I run `npm run start:prod` and it is 2994 when I run `npm run start:dev`. I copied all the code you showed including the startup script.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and I solved it by just adding `.trim()` after `process.env.NODE_ENV`. This is a part of `ConfigModule`:

```
ConfigModule.forRoot({
    envFilePath: [`${process.env.NODE_ENV.trim()}.env`],
}),
```